AWS Pinpoint add email header in Java
I would like to attach headers in Pinpoint when sending email so that I can track the emailEvents in down streams like SNS.
It's working fine in AWS console. I can see the "TrackingID" in the downstream, SNS topic.

Does anyone know how to config the header in the "SendMessageRequest"?
(in com.amazonaws.services.pinpoint.model)
My current approach is using simple email, but can't find a way to put the header
.withEmailMessage(new EmailMessage().withSimpleEmail(new SimpleEmail()
Thank you
